# Cannot Read Property 'length' of undefined - Don't Understand Why

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am getting an error and I do not understand why.  The error is saying "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

The code I have is:

```
outLetters = PC.substring(0,1);
var outLetters2 = PC.substring(1, 2);
outNumbers = Number(PC.substring(2,3));
currentPosition = outLetters;

console.log(secondLetters[currentPosition].length); //this returns 8

for(fl = 0; fl < firstLetter.length; fl++) {
    if(firstLetter[fl] === currentPosition) {

        console.log(secondLetters[currentPosition].length); //this returns 8

        for(number = 0; number < secondLetters[currentPosition].length; number++) { //this is where the error is showing
            if(secondLetters[currentPosition][number] === outLetters2) {
                currentPosition = PC.substring(0, 2);

                for(num = 0; num < outCodes[currentPosition.toUpperCase()].length; num++) {
                    if(outCodes[currentPosition.toUpperCase()][num] === outNumbers) {
                        valid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    } else {

        valid = false;
    }
}
```

I have commented a couple of lines because it seems to me that the length property is working until I put it in my for loop.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: firstLetter is never defined..at least not in the code you are showing us

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't want to put the full code on because there is quite a lot.  All the variables are defined correctly.  As I show above in the console.log it is returning the length of secondLetters[currentPostition].length but then when it is in the for loop it is not.

Comment: Okay. which line does the error come from? And does a `console.log(firstLetter[currentPosition].length);` also give a valid output? (you are outputting the length of secondLetters twice)

Comment: are you getting any results on *console.log(secondLetters.length);*

Comment: Obviously the `currentPosition = PC.substring(0, 2);`instruction within that loop yields the secondLetters[currentPosition][number]`` array inaccessible hence you get undefined as result

Comment: Thanks @Redu.  You say Obviously but I didn't realise this, hence the question...  it wasn't obvious to me (rookie).  I have added a `break;` statement at the end of the if within the erroring for loop and that works perfect.  Thanks everyone for your help.  I might add, I was wanting to exit that for loop once a match was found so I was just missing that `break;` statement.